# What is the molecular underpinning of pressure in fluid mechanics?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, viscosity, navier-stokes

The Navier-Stokes equation tells us that there are two ways of transferring momentum to an infinitesimal volume of fluid through the action surface forces: (1) pressure and (2) viscous stress.

On a molecular level, I understand that the viscous stress is due to molecular diffusion from a region of higher momentum to a region of lower momentum. This implies that viscous stress requires a velocity gradient to be present.

On the other hand, pressure does not require a velocity gradient. So the molecular origin of pressure must be different than the viscous stress. What is the molecular explanation of pressure?

Comment: Simple search on Google: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/13-4-kinetic-theory-atomic-and-molecular-explanation-of-pressure-and-temperature/

Comment: Also related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/gas-pressure-and-molecular-mass